# Are device-width and device-height not working properly in desktop browsers?

Tags: html, css, browser, media-queries, desktop

Im trying to experiment with `device-width` and `device-height` with my desktop and browser to distinguish to what extent does the property works and differences with the `width` when it comes to desktop browsers.

For some reason a simple code like this isnt very responsive with desktop browsers particulary firefox.
`@media screen and (max-device-width: 500px){
        body{
            background-color: green;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-device-width: 501px){
        body{
            background-color: red;
        }
    }`

then i tried resizing the browser only first declaration is being applied and turning to green?

anyone know why this is happening?
specifically does device-width and device-specific properties only work with mobile devices only and not desktop browsers?

Answer (score 2):

`device-width` refers to the width of the device itself (or the device's screen resolution) and is most commonly used for targeting specific mobile devices where browsers are not resized.  `device-width` can be used to target laptops as well usually with widths from 1200-1600px.

`width` refers to the width of the browser window (responsive to resizing).

Check out this link for the media queries for common devices: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Hope this helps!